# How to stop sorting ListView.AlphaSort

Tags: delphi, listview

Delphi Xe2. Listview (Lv1) with the big list items. Lv1 have standart compare procedure "TForm1.lv1Compare". Sorting is started by standard procedure lv1.AlphaSort; All works and is sorted normally. A question: how immediately to stop the started sorting in case of need?

example:

```
procedure tform1.button1.onclick(..);
begin
lv1.AlphaSort; // start sorting
end;

procedure tform1.button2.onclick(..);
begin
//lv1.StopSort; // stop sorting ???
end;
```

Or can be in procedure OnCompare there is any command of a stop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of the [`TListView.AlphaSort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TCustomListView.AlphaSort) the [`ListView_SortItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775131%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro is being called but I can't see any mention about how to stop the sorting process in the reference (even through the callback function), so I'm afraid this is not possible (at least regular way).

Like Sertac suggested in his comment, as one possible workaround might be to raise the silent exception inside of the OnCompare event:

```
var
  YouWantToAbortSort: Boolean;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  YouWantToAbortSort := False;
  ListView1.AlphaSort;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  YouWantToAbortSort := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Compare(Sender: TObject; Item1, Item2: TListItem;
  Data: Integer; var Compare: Integer);
begin
  if YouWantToAbortSort then
    Abort;
  // some sorting function here ...
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Comment: I guess you can use the regular 'OnCompare' to raise an exception.

Comment: Is that safe? Will the list view data be in a reasonable state if that happens? Won't it be partially sorted?

Comment: @David - The documentation says the contents are unstable *during* the sorting. AFAICS with my little testing there's no partial sort after the abort.

Comment: @David, difficult to say, reference is about the list view content during the sorting process quite scary, a few (simple) tests I've made now never failed. And yes, this will do the sorting just partially, but at this question OP sounds to don't care about.

Comment: IMO, the disadvantage to this method is that you have to put a ProcessMessages to test the condition.

Comment: I would solve this by an indirection sort. Create an array of integers and fill it with 0, 1, ..., N-1. Then sort that array so that the contents of the list view are not affected. Only if you get to the very end do you make the final changes. And of course I'd be using a virtual list view anyway which of course fits perfectly with indirection sort.

Comment: @David - You're thinking about some cache of item data I guess, otherwise in virtual mode you'd just invalidate the list I think..

Comment: @Sertac, that's right! Anohter common disadvantage for all VCL sorting events. It's necessary to process the user input messages to let the user interrupt the sorting somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Use [VirtualTreeView](http://www.delphi-gems.com/index.php/controls/virtual-treeview) instead of TListView and do the sort of your data in another thread. Then you'll have an ability to stop it any time.